# Web Service throwing lots of "An unexpected error occurred on a receive" when consumed after changing framework

Tags: c#, web-services, client-server

I had a web service written in .NET 2.0 that expose some web methods. This service is consumed by client application written with .NET 1.1 some years ago. The client application can't be converted at this point.

I have recently "upgraded" the web service project to .NET 4.0 as I've started using VS2010 and wanted to use the new features. As the client can't be upgraded I can't convert the web service to WCF, so the code itself is not changed at all. Same web service, same web methods.

In general it's working fine, and in the beginning I couldn't see any problem.

However, my log system is showing huge increase in "An unexpected error occurred on a receive" errors that happen when the client consume the web service - if for example it used to be once a week, it's now throwing those errors 10-20 times per day.

There are around 50 clients doing thousands of requests per day in total.

It does not happen in specific method and can't be reproduced to specific action made by some client.

Part of the Stack trace:

> > at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
> >     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
> >     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this increase? Any way to reduce it without converting the whole thing to WCF?

On second thought, this might also be caused because of installing the .NET 4.0 on the server, so I'm not sure rolling back the web service DLL to the old version will be any good.

The full error message is actually:

> The underlying connection was closed:
>   An unexpected error occurred on a
>   receive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of breaking changes for ASP.NET 4: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes, and also here: [.NET Framework 4 Migration Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx)

The only interesting piece I see in there would be the ASP.NET Request Validation chapter. Now validation also apply to web services.

I would try the `requestValidationMode="2.0"`.

Otherwise there is a full list of ideas here: [kb915599](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915599/en) but it's not related to the changes between .NET 4 and .NET 2.

Comment: I have increased the global timeout on the server and it reduced the amount of errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What endpoint binding are you using for the .NET 4 service? The default wshttpbinding is not support by previous versions on .net, you have to use the *BasicHttpBinding*.

Heres some guidance:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731134.aspx